# E2E testing with PhantomJS and Angular CLI

Tags: angular, phantomjs, protractor, angular-cli, e2e-testing

I need to run my E2E tests with PhantomJS because we use a continuous integration server that doesn't have any browsers installed. I use Protractor with Angular CLI but I haven't found any examples of configuration for PhantomJS. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web/blob/master/protractor.conf.js

Comment: This not working with angular-cli webpack

Comment: Works fine for me: https://travis-ci.org/textbook/known-for-web. If you're having problems, give a [mcve] that demonstrates them.

Comment: Well thank you for your reply.
I installed the latest angular-cli version and i tried your project.
The IHM is working but when i run ng e2e i got the same error like before:


[13:35:41] E/launcher - Error: Server terminated early with status 1
    at Error (native)
    at C:\Users\t662255\Downloads\known-for-web-master\known-for-web-master\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:242:20

Answer (score 4):

I'm running protractor tests against chrome inside a docker container using xvbf. It's arguably closer to a production like environment than PhantomJS and you can still run it "headless".

This is the docker image I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/shusson/chrome-tester/ which is based on https://hub.docker.com/r/webnicer/protractor-headless/

Comment: If using Docker, you can also `docker-compose` a network containing the Selenium server, one or more test browsers, your Angular 2 app and any backend APIs/services required.